# Splitting up Wordpress customizer array values

Tags: php, wordpress

Currently i'm rebuilding my website and i'm using the Wordpress customizer for setting up some homepage specific data into their corresponding sections.

I already have the data in place at the Wordpress backend but i'm having trouble splitting things up in the frontend.

I'm able to get all the Wordpress customizer values in an array and filter them based on the first part of the string for an section.

For example i'm using the following php code for filtering my timeline items:

```
<?php
    $home_options = get_theme_mods();

    foreach ($home_options as $key => $value) {
        if (strpos($key, "timeline_item") === 0) {
            echo '<strong>'.$key.'</strong> = '.$value.'<br />';
        }
    }
?>
```

This gives me the following data:

```
timeline_item_1_enable = 1
timeline_item_1_title = Test item 1
timeline_item_1_duration = 2010 - 2014
timeline_item_1_text = Test item 1 text
timeline_item_2_enable = 1
timeline_item_2_title = Test item 2
timeline_item_2_duration = 2014 - 2014
timeline_item_2_text = Test item 2 text
timeline_item_3_enable = 1
timeline_item_3_title = Test item 3
timeline_item_3_duration = 2010 - 2014
timeline_item_3_text = Test item 3 text
timeline_item_4_enable = 1
timeline_item_4_title = Test item 1
timeline_item_4_duration = 2010 - 2014
timeline_item_4_text = Test item 4 text
```

That's working fine, i'm getting all the timeline data i need. However from that data i want to extract all items that start with `timeline_item_1_` and bundle them into an `<div>`, same for `timeline_item_2_` etc etc

So the question is, how do i split up the result array any further and bundle all the items that belong to each other based on the first part of their string so the end result is as below,

```
<div>
timeline_item_1_enable = 1
timeline_item_1_title = Test item 1
timeline_item_1_duration = 2010 - 2014
timeline_item_1_text = Test item 1 text
</div>
<div>
timeline_item_2_enable = 1
timeline_item_2_title = Test item 2
timeline_item_2_duration = 2014 - 2014
timeline_item_2_text = Test item 2 text
</div>
<div>
timeline_item_3_enable = 1
timeline_item_3_title = Test item 3
timeline_item_3_duration = 2010 - 2014
timeline_item_3_text = Test item 3 text
</div>
<div>
timeline_item_4_enable = 1
timeline_item_4_title = Test item 1
timeline_item_4_duration = 2010 - 2014
timeline_item_4_text = Test item 4 text
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could hold the last index of item, and check if it is different to append your `<div>` and `</div>`.

```
$last_index = 0 ;
if (!empty($home_options)) {
    echo '<div>';
    foreach ($home_options as $key => $value) {
        if (strpos($key, "timeline_item") === 0) {
            $idx = explode('_', $key)[2] ; // get index of item
            if ($idx != $last_index) {
                if ($last_index != 0) {
                    echo '</div><div>' ;
                }
                $last_index = $idx;
            }
            echo '<strong>'.$key.'</strong> = '.$value.'<br />';
        }
    }
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Will outputs :

```
<div>
  <strong>timeline_item_1_enable</strong> = 1<br />
  <strong>timeline_item_1_title</strong> = Test item 1<br />
  <strong>timeline_item_1_duration</strong> = 2010 - 2014<br />
  <strong>timeline_item_1_text</strong> = Test item 1 text<br />
</div>
<div>
  <strong>timeline_item_2_enable</strong> = 1<br />
  <strong>timeline_item_2_title</strong> = Test item 2<br />
  <strong>timeline_item_2_duration</strong> = 2014 - 2014<br />
  <strong>timeline_item_2_text</strong> = Test item 2 text<br />
</div>
<div>
  <strong>timeline_item_3_enable</strong> = 1<br />
  <strong>timeline_item_3_title</strong> = Test item 3<br />
  <strong>timeline_item_3_duration</strong> = 2010 - 2014<br />
  <strong>timeline_item_3_text</strong> = Test item 3 text<br />
</div>
<div>
  <strong>timeline_item_4_enable</strong> = 1<br />
  <strong>timeline_item_4_title</strong> = Test item 1<br />
  <strong>timeline_item_4_duration</strong> = 2010 - 2014<br />
  <strong>timeline_item_4_text</strong> = Test item 4 text<br />
</div>
```

Comment: Just tested it and it works like expected!

Looks like an working and pretty "straight forward and failsafe" solution to me...

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $home_options = get_theme_mods();
    $regex = '/([a-z]*)_([a-z]*)_(\d)_([a-z]*)/';
    $parts = [];

    foreach ($home_options as $key => $value) {
       preg_match_all($regex, $key, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
       /* $matches have the matches below
       Full match   0-22    `timeline_item_1_enable`
       Group 1. 0-8 `timeline`
       Group 2. 9-13    `item`
       Group 3. 14-15   `1`
       Group 4. 16-22   `enable`
       */  
        $pkey = 'timeline_item_'.$matches[0][3]; 
        if (!isset($parts[$pkey])) $parts[$pkey] = array($key => $val);
        else $parts[$pkey][$key] = $val;
    }

    foreach($parts as $pkey => $props) {
      echo '<div>';
      foreach($props as $key => $val) {
        echo $key . ' = ' . $val . '<br>';
      } 
      echo '</div>';
    } 
?>
```

check regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/cdQyrh/1).

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_chunk to split the array in fours with preserve keys true and loop each set of fours in a inner loop.

```
Foreach(array_chunk($arr, 4, true) as $val){
    Echo "<div>\n";
    Foreach($val as $key => $v){
        echo '<strong>'.$key.'</strong> = '.$v."<br />\n";
    }
    Echo "</div>\n";
}
```

https://3v4l.org/Ytigd